# Select Input in a PHP form overwriting before printing

Tags: php, forms

So the problem I'm having is that when I submit this form to a new page, if I only check one row, then the Quantity I'm sending is correct. If I Check and submit more than one row then the Quantity is being overwritten and both Quantities are printed as the last value. My question is how do I make it so the quantity isn't overwritten before I am able to print.

When I try to send them as an array, what happens is it will send an array of all of the Quantities for every row, including the ones that aren't Checked.

```
while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($runquery))
{
    $id = $result['gme_id'];
    $title = $result['gme_title'];
    $type = $result['gme_type'];
    $dateavail = $result['gme_date_avail'];
    $price = $result['gme_price'];

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td bgcolor='$color'>$title</td>";
        echo "<td>$type</td>";
        echo "<td>$id</td>";
        echo "<td>$price</td>";
        if($dateavail < date('Y-M-D'))
        {
            echo "<td>
                <select name=\"quantity[]\">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </td>";                     

            echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"selectedgame[]\" value=\"$id\"></td>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<td>$dateavail</td>";
            echo "<td></td>";
        }

    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Here is the code for the second page.

```
$gameid = $_POST["selectedgame"];
foreach($gameid as $value)
{
    echo "$value <br />";


    $query = "SELECT * FROM gametbl WHERE gme_id = $value";

    $runquery = mysqli_query($myCon, $query);

    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($runquery);

        while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($runquery))
        {
            $id = $value;
            $title = $result['gme_title'];
            $price = $result['gme_price'];
            $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];

            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>$title</td>";
                echo "<td>$id</td>";        
                echo "<td>$quantity</td>";
                echo "<td>$price</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
}
```

Here are the results I'm getting

When I've only checked on row:

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

When I have more than one row checked:

[image: screenshot3]

[image: screenshot4]

Any help is appreciated. I'm still fairly new to web design and I'm trying to remake a project from my php class that I had taken over a year ago. I've tried contacting my professor from that class, but I haven't gotten a response from him and I emailed him over 4 weeks ago now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just gave the array index referring to the game.

```
<select name=\"quantity[]\">
```

to

```
<select name=\"quantity[$id]\">
```

And in your second page

```
 $quantity = $_POST['quantity'][$id];
```

And I would like to suggest using a payment gateway, because to store credit card number your network would need to be audited to be PCI compliant.

Comment: Awesome! It worked, I didn't know you could do that!